# Calculating electric potential

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, integration

When caculating electric potential using $dV = -E\cdot dl$ when the distribution of $E$ is known, how do we determine the upper and lower limit for the integration?

Comment: I think you would use the starting position and the end position. Infinity is frequently used for one of the limits of integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits of integration entirely depend on what scenario is even being considered, in terms of distance from the source. If considering an electrostatic point charge, the lower limit will usually be 0, as this is the closest possible distance to the source, while the upper limit will be infinity, as this is the furthest possible distance from the source (the field permeates this far but tends to zero).

If the source of the field is not a point charge, but rather a source with volume (such as a uniformly charged sphere with a known radius R), then the electric potential inside the object and outside the object need to be solved as separate integrals. For the integral for the electric potential outside the uniform sphere, the lower limit would change to R and the upper limit to infinity, whereas the integral for the electric potential inside the uniform sphere would have a lower limit of 0 and an upper limit of R. In each case, any different electric field values would also need to be considered.